# Azure deployment error after renewing SSL certificate

Tags: azure, ssl

Just renewed our SSL certificate and uploaded to Azure and changed the thumbprint in the ServiceConfiguration files and I am getting an error when I try to deploy:

"The service upgrade package specifies input endpoint HttpsIn, which differs from the deployed endpoint for role TimeClock. The upgrade package must specify identical endpoints in order to perform an in-place upgrade."

How would I then go about updating this deployment now that I have a new SSL thumbprint?

Cheers,
Le-roy

Answer (score 0):

It might be a limitation that your unable to complete an in-place upgrade. Could you try uploading your package to your staging environment? If this deploys successfully then you'll be able to switch your staging deployment, promoting this to production.

Comment: @Le-roy - Have you been able to renew your SSL?

Answer (score 0):

same issue here during renew of SSL:

My workaround I did delete the production deployment (**not** the cloud service & deployment) 
You will lose your Virtual IP (VIP) anyways.

Upload like new deployment, and new SSL is used :-)
Btw, change new cert to use the old name (in Visual Studio) is not an option as I get the same error in Azure:

> The service upgrade package specifies input endpoint HttpsIn, which differs from the deployed endpoint for role MyPortal. The
>   upgrade package must specify identical endpoints in order to perform
>   an in-place upgrade. The long running operation tracking ID was:
>   596___42sfafsdfa.

For the future, try to renew SSL and keep the thumbprint somehow if possible.

Comment: You can upload to the staging deployment and then do a VIP swap, as referenced in the other answer. That way you keep your public IP, don't have any down time, and don't have to worry about changing thumbprints.